# Email validation not working with textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, uitextfield

Hi i want to validate email address at the time when user input text in text field. when wrong email then showing alert and return no to stay in email textfield it's working on return and textfield end editing but not working on textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange.
Please if some one know how to do it share it please Thanks in advance .
here is my sample code for validation in return

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeTextfield=textField;
    if(activeTextfield==txtCon1Email || activeTextfield==txtCon1SecondMail ||   activeTextfield==txtCon2Email || activeTextfield==txtCon2SecondMail)
  {
     NSString *emailReg = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
     NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailReg];

     if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:textField.text] == NO)
      {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OTS" message:@"Please enter valid email address." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];



        isvalidemail=NO;


    }
    else
        isvalidemail=YES;

 }
}
```

but i want to do it on when text is entered by user

Comment: Why do you want to validate at input of every char, a char is not an valid email . You need to go with the  `textFieldDidEndEditing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be enough for your situation : Just try with `textFieldDidEndEditing` delegate only :

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if ([textField.text length]==0 || [self validateEmailWithString:textField.text]) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];

    }else{
       [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OTS" message:@"Please enter valid email address." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];

        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)validateEmailWithString:(NSString*)email
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method, then be aware that every **last added character** is in the `replacementString` and the rest before typing the new character is in the `textField.text`.

So when validating the email you need to combine the textField.text and the replacementString like this:

[image: shouldChange]

Remember that when you use textField.text **you are missing the last character** and if you use the replacementString **you only get the last added character**.